# Restore default keymap

Tags: keymap

I followed a tutorial to install an addon that change the keymap. However, I found that some of the keys that I familiar with changed and is not convenient. I note that there is a "Load factory setting" under [File][Default]. Can this change the keymap back to the default keymap? Besides, would this "Load factory setting" delete addon installed?

Thank you

Comment: It is possible that the add-on is written well enough that disabling it might undo the change.  Have you tried that?  Also, it might help if you could add a URL pointing to the specific add-on.  And yes, loading factory settings _should_ restore the keymap but it will also reset everything else.  It would not delete the add-on but it should(?) disable it.  Best to disable / uninstall it first yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. For unknow reason, [Edit][Preference][Keymap]"Keymap-D" was selected. After I change it back to "Blender", it restore to original setting.